# In PhpStorm can I prevent code expansion on cursor movement?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have vim enabled and every time I navigate a document up/down any code that is folded will be expanded. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

**Edit:** the code is expanded when the cursor is placed over the folded code

Comment: Which version of PhpStorm do you have?

Comment: version: 2016.3.2